# Conversion from string "-1" to type 'Integer' is not valid, but the String value IS a valid int

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, casting

I'm encountering a VERY strange issue with only one user of my software.

As stated in the title I'm receiving the following error:

```
Conversion from string "-1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
```

Some of the older code in the application uses the VB call GetSettings to retrieving registry information, below is its signature and an example of the use in the app:

```
Public Function GetSetting(ByVal AppName As String, ByVal Section As String, ByVal Key As String, Optional ByVal Default As String = "") As String
```

Which is used as follows throughout older (8 years+) portions of the app:

```
GetSetting("My App", "Section", "Key", "-1")
```

So, if the registry key isn't found GetSettings returns the string "-1".  In the code this is mostly used as follows...

```
Dim regValue as Integer = GetSetting("My App", "Section", "Key", "-1")
```

... without any sort of casting into an integer like CInt(GetSetting("My App", "Section", "Key", "-1")) etc.  I realize this may be bad coding practice, however, in VB.net as long as the assignment is valid (i.e. GettSetting's default value is actually a string of a valid integer and not "adasd" or "", for example) it should work (I realize this is not the case in c# where a cast would be necessary for successful compilation).

To test this further, I have gone into my registry and set all Keys to -1 as well as completely deleted all keys (so that the default value would be used) and was unable to reproduce the issue.  The only way I was able to reproduce a similar error was by setting one of the registry keys to "-1" (with the quotes in the key value) and received pretty much the exact same error:

```
Conversion from string ""-1"" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

This makes sense, however, as the registry value isn't a valid integer anymore due to the added quotes ("-1" vs ""-1"").

There are ~3000 people who use the app daily, and no one else is experiencing this issue other than this one user, this code has also not changed in 8+ years (newer code does not use the registry anymore).

I've tried re-installing .NET and the app on the users machine, as well as looking in the users control panel for any odd regional settings etc, but have yet to be able to find a resolution to the issue.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it consistently reproducible for that one user, or is it sporadic even for that user?

Comment: It is consistent with the user and happens in every form that uses the GetSettings call.  A head scratcher, for sure.

Comment: How about if you write a test app that does nothing but calls `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger("-1")` and have that user run it.  Is that a possibility?  If so, I'd be curious to know what happens in that scenario.

Comment: It might be worth looking at the number formats in the offending user's regional settings.

Comment: Are you able to look and see what the value of the following registry key is on their computer: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sNegativeSign`

Comment: The user is a couple timezones ahead of me, so once I'm able to get on his computer and check this out I'll come back with my findings.  Thanks.

Comment: Alright, so I didn't get a hold of the user yet, but, I changed my registry setting (sNegativeSign) to a bracket, deleted all my registry keys for my app to ensure it would use the default value of -1 (from the GetSettings call) and my app still worked fine.  I also went into the control panel and set negatives to display with brackets i.e. (1) instead of -1 and my app still worked as well.

Comment: Ok i set sNegativeSign to be blank and I reproduced the error the user is seeing!  Make a answer and I will accepted it once I verify that this solves the issue on the users machine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger` method uses the regional settings to parse strings.  Make sure that the value of the following registry key is correct: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sNegativeSign`

Comment: Just to add a little more info to this:  in my case the sNegativeSign key was set to be blank (empty string? null? - not sure what the registry uses in this case, so I'll call it blank) which caused my issue.  I played around in the Control Panel under Regional settings and tried to change the value of the Negative sign in the UI in an attempt to get a blank saved to the registry but was unsuccessful.  I guess this could be a seperate question, but I have no idea how one of my users (who isn't too computer savvy) would have manged to change this registry value.  Very bizzare.

Comment: Damn it, I had to be the first to answer that! Damn this mobile internet :-P